# Forcebly stop EA in OnTick()

Tags: mql4, mt4

I am making a EA for backTest.

Normally program works like this.

1. `Ontick()` is called until the end of certain period.
2. `OnDeinit()` `OnTester()` are called.

However now I want to stop in `OnTick()` and goto 2).

like this,

```
void OnTick()
{
    if (cnt > 100) {OnTick();OnTester();//Finish program here}
}
```

I think I could stop in `OnInit()` (to check user's initial setup etc...)
However can I stop EA in `OnTick()`???

In summary, what I want to do is,

Call `OnTester()` from inside of the `OnTick()` and finish the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, this is also possible:

syntax is:

```
void  ExpertRemove();
```

> The Expert Advisor is not stopped immediately as you call `ExpertRemove();` just a flag to stop the EA operation is set. That is, any next event won't be processed, `OnDeinit()` will be called and the Expert Advisor will be unloaded and removed from the chart.

So the `OnDeinit(){...}`-handler is activated "automatically", once a first call to the `ExpertRemove()` system function has raised the pre-termination flag.

If your logic requires, put this call into a "manually" called `OnTester()` handler, relying on it being invoked as posted above
`if( cnt > 100 ) { OnTester(); // having the "killer"-ExpertRemove() there ... }`

and you are done.

You might have noticed, there should not be the posted `OnTick()`-call inside the `if(){...}`-code-block, as it would never let the code-execution reach the manually-pre-scribed call to the `OnTester()`, but will remain in a lethal never ending loop of manually-injected endless diving of re-entries into the `OnTick(){...}`-handler, having no way to exit from.

Comment: Thanks it works well!, I didn't need to add `OnTester()` manually, it was called automatically by `ExpertRemove()`. I just added like this `if( cnt > 100 ) { ExpertRemove();}`